# Calculate the line integral without specific range

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question to calculate the line integral $\int_c A.dr$, where $A = \frac{-y\vec i + x\vec j}{x^2+y^2}$, and the curve C is given by the equation $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ and $Z=0$. All the line integrals calculation I know upto my current knowledge is using some kind of range. But here range is not given. If anyone could give me some pointers, I shall be highly thankful.
I tried two approaches:

**First approach**
$$
r=x\vec i + y \vec j
\implies dr=dx\vec i + dy\vec j \\
A.dr = \frac{-ydx}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}
\\
\implies \int_c \vec A.\vec r = \int_c \frac{-ydx}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}
$$
Then after this, if I substitute x and y in terms of a but what would be the limits of curve c.

**Second approach:**
If I go with parametrization approach  i.e. $x = acos(t)$ and $y=asin(t)$ then $dx/dt = acos(t) \:and\: dy/dt = asin(t)$ as:
$$
L = \int_a^b f(x,y)ds=\int_a^b f(x(t), y(t))\sqrt{{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2}}.dt
$$
But by solving and putting the limits $0\le t \le 2\pi$ gives me zero result. Also, this problem can't be solved using green's theorem because it also gives zero result.

Comment: What's the curl of your function?  (This is a Green's Theorem problem.)

Comment: it is zero, possibly, Because if we differentiate first term w.r.t y and second w.r.t x it is zero.

Comment: I calculated 2-d curl, and it turned out to be zero.

Comment: So you have all the pieces and your conclusion is correct.  The answer is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I was confused whether I was doing correct calculations.

Comment: @B.Goddard can you help me about an equation, as I couldn't figure what kind of equation is? and how to find the solution. if,ψ=sin⁡(kr/r),then show that ∇^2 ψ+k^2 ψ=0